# How to isolate battery AND PV with single pole switch

Tags: switches, solar-cell

I have a battery powered microcontroller system which is charged by a solar panel via an LM317 fixed voltage regulator. It's simple, but works well; the PV is only 5W and the voltage is set to 16.4V ... battery is 16.8V Li-Ion.

- When I ship the product to customers, or store on the shelf, it needs to be 100% powered down so that the battery stays full.
- When the PV panel is plugged in but the box is not turned on, the system needs to be powered down so that it does not run.
- I don't mind if the battery charges from the PV while the electronics are powered down, but it would be better (safer) if the charging system was also stopped when the button was off.
- I need to be able to trim the LM317 to exactly 16.4V when the PV is plugged in and the battery is disconnected, during manufacturing, so I can't 'shut it down' to 1.25V by taking ADJ to GND when the battery is unplugged.

I have not yet found a way to do this with a single pole switch (it needs to be a small IP67 push button). Any ideas welcome! Here is my schematic so far. This option leaks ~1.8mA through the R23/24 network.

[image]

Comment: I would change it so that the switch disconnects the battery, then add an N mosfet clamp to the solar panel output and/or the 12v bus to keep the solar panel from powering up the MCU in the batteries absence.

Comment: Sounds like a valid suggestion @Drew - putting it on the 12v bus would be better allowing me to trim the LM317 while battery is out. I'm not experienced with choosing MOSFETs, anything you'd recommend for these voltages? Max current charge from the MCU side (marked 12v) is 500mA.

Comment: I think I might need a schematic to help me understand your point. Where would I take the gate of the FET? How can it know whether power is being provided by battery or PV?

Comment: The fuse in the gnd path is probably not a good idea. A fault could backfeed via the PV and cause an issue. Best to fuse the + of the battery and the PV if necessary.

Comment: Use the single pole switch to control MOSFET switches wherever required.